# Delete query in MyBatis is not deleting anything

Tags: java, sql-server, mybatis

I am relatively new in MyBatis. 
The select queries are working fine. But the delete queries and not working.

Mapper.xml

```
<delete id="deleteEntry" parameterType="java.util.HashMap"  >
        delete from table where  user_id = #{userId} and application_id = #{appId}
</delete>
```

Mapper.java

```
public interface Mapper {
    public Integer deleteEntry(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("appId") long appId);
}
```

The DAO where I am calling the function looks like this.

```
        SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            LOG.info("Records Deleted: "+sqlSession.getMapper(Mapper.class).deleteEntry(userId,appId));
        }
        finally {
            sqlSession.close();
        }
```

Now the result is 
Records Deleted: 1

However when i check the database, the row hasn't been deleted.
I am using Sql Server.

Thank you for the help in advance. :)

Comment: How about if you use a static sql (*use real arguments in sql rather than variables*) to detect whether is a managed-session or wrong arguments problem?

Comment: @holi-java Tried it. Still the same result. No rows deleted in db. But still get 1 as output. I tried providing it arguments for rows which don't exist in the db expecting to get 0 as the return value, but still got 1. Added a syntax error to the query. Got an exception. So I believe the query is fine.

Comment: @ParthSingh `openSession()` disables auto-commit implicitly ([doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html#sqlSessions)). Try 1) calling `sqlSession.commit()` explicitly before calling `close()` or 2) opening session in auto-commit mode (i.e. `sqlSession.openSession(true)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set auto-commit to true

```
SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(true);
```